# Have issues while trying to access specific URI in Websphere 7.0 version

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, websphere

There is some update activity in Websphere server.After update i am not able to access my specific URI present in specific package, but i am able to access other link in my application

It throws the below error

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: 
SRVE0202E: Servlet was found, but is corrupted:
SRVE0227E: Check that the class resides in the proper package directory. done
SRVE0228E: Check that the classname has been defined in the server using the proper case and fully qualified package. done 
SRVE0229E: Check that the class was transferred to the filesystem using a binary transfer mode. 
SRVE0230E: Check that the class was compiled using the proper case (as defined in the class definition).
SRVE0231E: Check that the class file was not renamed after it was compiled.
```

I have checked the naming Convention , package casing , have compiled the file and place the file in area

But unable to find what is wrong.Please suggest some solution

Comment: How did you update your application?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/359899/Servlets/java/Servlet-corrupt-message - This one is kind of old but the summary is that basically the servlet was compiled with wrong Java version.

Comment: java version on my local machine and websphere are at same version...I have compiled the file from my local machine and put that on the server


Update was done by some other team ...I am not sure about the method of update
But after the update classes files corrupted issue is.coming for set of files from particular directory 

Rest other menus are working fine in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved now.
Path mentioned in the shared lib for the classes folder was incorrect.
It is working after the valid path is mentioned.

Before that it is referring to the classes folder from web-inf classes in war folder and there were no file present at that path